# How do I redirect specific file extensions from one directory (that no longer exists) to another?

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite

We have just moved to a new site structure and some of our old directories no longer exist. Our old directory `/html/` held both `.jpg` and `.pdf` files. Those files have now been moved into their own directories ( `/images/` and `/documents/` respectively).

How can I use the root `.htaccess` file to redirect all links that were pointing to the `/html/` directory for `.pdf` and `.jpg` files to the current `/documents/` and `/images/` directory?

In other words, if a link comes in for `www.example.com/html/.pdf` I would like it to be directed to `www.example.com/documents/.pdf`.

Likewise for `.jpg` requests, if a link comes in for `www.example.com/html/.jpg` I would like it to be redirected to `www.example.com/images/.jpg`.

I have tried several different rewrite rules from this site but I can't seem to adjust the syntax to my exact needs.

I'm currently trying to use this type of code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^html/*.pdf$ "https://www.example.com/documents/$1" [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this rewrites in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^html\/(.*)\.pdf$ https://www.example.com/documents/$1.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^html\/(.*)\.jpg$ https://www.example.com/images/$1.jpg [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Fantastic! This worked perfectly. Thank you so very much!